# How to force a CSS file to be the last one rendered in the angular project?

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I used `angular` with bootstrap themes, I would usually add the theme's css and javascript files to `angular.json`. This way, I was always able to add a `custom.css` file to the end of the list, where I would be able override to other css rules.

I recently started studying `angular-material`, and it "injects" (idk if this is the right term) the components' CSS inside `<style>` tags. This way, my `custom.css` file is not the last of the batch, therefore my overrides don't work.

So, my question is: how do I guarantee my `custom.css` is the last to be rendered, or injected, in the HTML file generated by angular? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In theory, the components' styles should be the ones that take precedence, that's why there are scoped to components.... why not putting global styles in `styles.css`?

Comment: @IvanS95 thanks for the input. Well, idk why, but I don't have a `styles.css` in my project. I am using a starter template from a framework. I will create a new angular application using the cli, will try to adding some css to the `styles.css` and check if it works.